# Cover page image update automatically on Facebook fan page

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using this script to upload and set an image as a FB page cover image.
It's working fine, but it does not automatically set the image as cover.
Can you please suggest the modification required in this, please?

I have found this tag for auto update, but don't know how to use it:

```
$json_object = $facebook->api("/Fan_Page_ID/?access_token=".$pageAccessToken,'post',$make_cover_image);
```

I am not able to add existing code in this post.
It's showing, that the code can't be submitted even if I add ``.

Comment: What are you trying to say? What do you mean by ` its working fine but its not auto set the image for cover images`?

Comment: Hi,i am able to upload the image in page album but not able to set this automatically as a cover images. After uploading i am redirecting user to set the image, please see the old code `$photo = $facebook->api($album_id . '/photos', 'post', $args);

if( is_array( $photo ) && !empty( $photo['id'] ) ){
    echo '<p><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Apps/34523542?preview_cover='.$photo['id'].'">Click here to set the cover pic</a></p>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a cover photo for a Page by issuing an `HTTP POST` to `/PAGE_ID` with a `Page Access Token` and the parameter:

> **cover** 
>   
> The ID of the photo

See here for Page Access Token: [Page Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens)

See here for more details: [Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)

---

**Code**

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$accounts = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
for($i=0;$accounts['data'][$i];$i++)
{
    $page_access_token=$accounts['data'][$i]['access_token'];
    $page_id = $accounts['data'][$i]['id'];

    $facebook->setAccessToken($page_access_token);
    $args = array('name' => 'awesome album name', 'message' => 'awesome album message');
    try 
    {
        $album_id =$facebook->api("/$page_id/albums", 'post', $args);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    $args = array('image' =>'@'.realpath('/var/www/facebook.png'));
    try
    {
       $uploaded_photo_details = $facebook->api("/{$album_id['id']}/photos", 'post', $args);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
       echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    if(isset($uploaded_photo_details['id']))
    {
        $args = array('cover' => $uploaded_photo_details['id'], 'offset_y' =>0);
        try 
        {
           $cover_details = $facebook->api("/{$page_id}", 'post', $args);
        } 
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
           echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HI,thanks for you input... i tried but its showing error for post method, tested in Graph API Explorer, same error found there too, have selected application which i am using to access this. {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 10
  }
}

Comment: You have the `publish_stream permission?

Comment: You first have to upload the photo to an album. I'll share the complete working code :) And pls dont forget to accept the answer if worked!

Comment: Hi Shandowfax, thanks a lot for your effort but i am still not able to integrate it,after adding your code, getting this error - Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. I am surely missing soemthing, please help, i will surely accept the answer.

Comment: Hi Shandowfax, Manual working script is here. Please help. `http://ipt.pw/5FSnCl`

Comment: The code i've posted is working.! You may be getting `An active access token must be used to query information about the current user` at `/me/accounts`; so with this call just provide the `access_token`

Comment: is the same, please see the code - 1. used_access_tocken -`ipt.pw/8vzfmf` , 2. You hosted code - `ipt.pw/P2pJvI` and your code same as i have used on the page - `ipt.pw/0MQubH`

Comment: Why did you replace `['access_token']` with your own token? You dont have to do that `access_token` is a fields name. After correcting this, let me  check the page_access_token in the debugger tool and then let me know the status!

Comment: I have replaced the access token with ['access_token'] but still the same error, you can see the used code here.. ipt.pw/0MQubH . how will this work if we wont use any access token? please help.

Comment: Where is the authorization code? `$accounts` must me null since you have not auth/login the user. pls check the vlaue of `$accounts`

Comment: See, you can only make the calls like `/me/API` when the user is in session,.

Comment: Thanks a ton, finally worked. user authentication was missing. :) Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Hi – Shadowfax, need little more help, hope you wont mind. Current script is working great but creating new album (awesome album name) on each upload, we would like to use already created gallery, please guide.

Comment: You can upload the photo to a single album, instead of creating the album each time, just post the photo with - `/MY_ALBUM_ID/PHOTO`

Comment: thanks Shadowfax, working great :-) need little more modification, please help. can we hide these posts from timeline, he there any function for this, fb page url is `ipt.pw/2Eoi6S`. i have posted it here but no response. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703164/how-to-delete-hide-facebook-page-cover-images-update-feed-from-timeline`

Comment: `hide these posts from timeline`- i dont think you can. I'll update the answer in the post. Pl check! :)

Comment: Hi, this script is posting image on all fb pages :( what to do if i need to post on one page, where to define the ID.

Comment: Try to understand the script. Instead of the fir lood simply use the page id of the page id of the page where u want to post the img . Simple